# Out of office notification from SharePoint calendar list

Tags: 2013, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

I have calendar list of absence on SharePoint site that is synced with MS Outlook. I want to make **Out of office** notification for each user if he/she creates item in SP calendar list.
Is it possible to do and if yes how?